# My program changes the elements of the array inside the function without me changing it explicitly. How does it happen?

Tags: java, arrays, function, swap

So I am writing a function which should swap the first and last element of the array and return the modified array. My code is as follows:

```
public static int[] swapEnds(int[] nums) {

    int newArray[] = new int[nums.length];
    newArray = nums; // copies all the elements to the new array
    newArray[0] = nums[nums.length -1 ]; // changes the first element of the newArray
    newArray[newArray.length-1] = nums[0]; // changes the last element of the newArray

    return newArray;
}
```

By doing some debugging, I found out that nums[0] has been changed somehow, but I did not make that change anywhere in my code. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
newArray = nums; // copies all the elements to the new array
```

No, this does not copy elements to the new array, it copies the reference of the original array to the `newArray` variable, which means there's just one array and both the `nums` and `newArray` variables point to it. Therefore you are modifying the original array.

Use `newArray = Arrays.copyOf(nums,nums.length);` to create a copy of the array.

EDIT: You actually create a new array here - `int newArray[] = new int[nums.length];` - but then you do nothing with this array.

Comment: Nitpick: *"it copies the reference"* kind of sounds like the same thing, maybe "points to" or something similar instead, but maybe a discussion on "pointers" isn't worth avoiding ;)

Comment: I tried with newArray = Arrays.copy(nums,nums.length); the compiler is not liking it .

Comment: @Harry sorry, it's actually copyOf

Comment: Works perfect now. Thanks! But yes I still need some help with pointers/reference. Could you recommend any article? Specifically for Arrays

Comment: @Harry Just read any Java book/tutorial. Perhaps this one - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html